# Map nullable column to non-nullable bool and make sure querying works

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a database column of type `number(1)` that doesn't have a not null constraint.
In my entity I have a simply `bool` property.
The value of the property is `false` when it is `NULL` in the database. That's expected and wanted.

The problem now is that querying doesn't work the same way.

`session.Query<Entity>(x => !x.Property)` returns only those entities with `0` in the column, not those with `NULL`.

Is there any way to tell NHibernate to do this?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE column IS NULL` would be the easiest way. However you could try to use a IUserType which has 2 Columns (with the same name) and set both in NullSafeSet.

Comment: @Firo: Thanks for the comment. I went with the update already.

Answer (score -1):

"!NULL" in sql is not true. Null is undefined and not equal to false. You can check if x.Property == null.

Comment: Please read the question again. My property is a `bool` which can't be `null`.

Comment: So why don't you make it a "bool?"

Comment: Because it really can only be true or false. NULL means the same as false.